# How to disable upload options from slides field in the redux framework

Tags: wordpress, plugins, redux-framework

I can disable upload option from slides field on Redux framework. I have read documentation here https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/slides/, but I didn't find any solution so I need a proper way to disable this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you can disable by css custom class.

Comment: No i want to disable redux framework option

Answer (score 0):

Use this css. **Remember css should be nested**

```
{
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #my_portfolio-why_me .upload_button_div {
          display: none;
        }
    </style>

<?php
}
add_action('admin_head', 'add_styles');
```

Comment: It's not right way ,if i use another slide what i should now?